# if indexmatch = #N/A keep original cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 worksheets in excel. 
Sheet 1 is a price list given to us by a supplier
Sheet 2 is a list of all the products we supply (can be from multiple suppliers).
In the first column of each Sheet is the Product Code and the second column is the price. I have done an index match in the Price column of Sheet 2 to get the price info from Sheet 1(this contains up to date prices). The index match works but if I have a product in sheet 2 that isn’t in sheet 1 I don’t want the price in sheet 2 to change.
I think I need to do an IF Function in VBA….but I don’t know how to go about doing it!

Comment: Could you provide some relevant test data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to @Jonno 's answer, an Iferror in a separate column is probably best. Something along the lines of this should work in cell c2, the column of which which I would title "Updated Price":

```
=Iferror(<<<EXISTING INDEX MATCH FORMULA HERE>>>,b2)
```

What this will do is run your index match formula and pull the correct price. If it can't do this, it will return the existing price. This will change this:

```
Product ID        Price    
     1             3.50                  
     2             #N/A
```

To this

```
Product ID   Original Price     Updated Price
     1             2.50             3.50     
     2             2.50             2.50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IFERROR function to handle what to do with #N/A results.

For example

```
=IFERROR(YourLookup,10.5)
```

This would return the result of the lookup if it's successful, or 10.5 if it fails to find a result.